# Como forçar o jest a não rodar testes sobre interfaces no Typescript

Tags: typescript, jest

Olá, tenho um projeto construído em Typescript e nele estou usando o Jest (ts-jest) para fazer os testes. Ao rodar o jest com o comando `--coverage` percebi que ele está passando sobre linhas de código que representam apenas interfaces, ex:

*src/presentation/protocols/controller.ts*

```
import {IHttpRequest, IHttpResponse} from './http';

export interface IController {
  handle(httpRequest: IHttpRequest): Promise<IHttpResponse>;
}
```

No coverage ele está buscando esses arquivo e dizendo que não há cobertura sobre as linhas de 1 a 5 mas uma interface não é um código "testável" portanto realmente não teria como ter cobertura disso.

O que preciso fazer para que o jest não faça a cobertura de interfaces ou elementos semelhantes como enums e tipos?

Comment: Que comando está a executar para correr os testes? Pode passar um argumento com uma regex. Por exemplo `jest '**/tests/**/*.test.ts'` irá correr testes que sejam encontrados em ficheiros com extensão `.test.ts` e que no seu caminho tenham uma pasta `tests`.

Comment: O problema não é nos arquivo de testes mas de cobertura. Não há cobertura a ser feita em uma interface dessa, ela não é código tratável... Seria a mesma coisa de eu querer fazer a cobertura de um comentário